# Get NodeJS module scope

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to access module scope like this?

```
class A {}

let i = new ???['A']();
```

Comment: `'A'` is just a string.  `A` is a declared variable that's in scope in main.js; what are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: How to get the main.js scope?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you inside main.js and trying to figure out if a file has been required in main.js, or are you outside?  As far as I know Node does not track what files `require` things -- it will resolve modules, but the exposure of that module to a file is just via variable assignment which isn't specific to `require`

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your goal is to be able to instantiate classes by name.

In that case, just create a registry yourself:

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}

const registry = {A, B, C};

console.log(registry);
console.log(new registry['A']());
```

This prints out

```
{ A: [class A], B: [class B], C: [class C] }
A {}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know this approach and was wondering if it is possible to access the scope directly.

Comment: It's not, not that I know of.